# Documentation of linphone (open source sip library) for iphone

Tags: ios

Can anybody help me to find the developers documentation of linphone for iOS.
I want to understand the architecture and functionality of the project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that apart from http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/ (that you've supposedly seen already) there is no documentation on this project. You will need to read the source code if you need more information about the architecture/etc. Since open source projects are developed very often in the author's spare time, it is quite common that they concentrate on the actual code writing instead of drawing architectural diagrams and design documents.

If you need a SIP stack for iOS I would recommend you to have a look at [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/). It is definitely a more mature project with extensive documentation on every level.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is google the function you want to check, and then there will be many documentation links. Those documentation may be different because of different versions. I think it is enough for you.

For example:
http://fossies.org/dox/linphone-3.5.2/index.html